# DNS MX priority, why does everyone start with 10

Tags: dns

My question is, why does everyone start the priority with 10, 20, 30, etc...

Is there a reason for that or is just somthing that everyone do for no reason.

Comment: "why does everyone"? Everyone? Plural of anecdote is not data. See `MX` records of `stackoverflow.com` for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shortly, this is a convention among system managers. Some of the mail server providers suggests "10, 20, 30.." some of them "10, 100, 200,.." and some of them "5, 10, 15,.." etc.

IMHO this is because if you set to 1 the lowest priority server. and in an emergency case you want to set an 0 case you can not. In traditional the versioning or prioritization is done by "10, 20, 30, .." with enough space between them so because in some extra cases you can use that space.

To sum up, this is a conventional usage of the prioritization.